# What is the best way to share a big read-only structure between two threads?

Tags: multithreading, rust, shared-memory

One thread calculates some data that takes about 1GB of RAM and another thread only reads this data. What is the best way to implement this?

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {

    let mut shared: i32 = 0; // will be changed to big structure

    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            shared += 1;
            println!("write shared {}", shared);
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
        }
    });

    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
            println!("read shared = ???"); // <---------------- ????
        }
    });

    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(4));
    println!("main");
}
```

You can run [this code online](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=use%20std%3A%3Athread%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Atime%3A%3ADuration%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20shared%3A%20i32%20%3D%200%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20thread%3A%3Aspawn(move%20%7C%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20loop%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shared%20%2B%3D%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22write%20shared%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20shared)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20thread%3A%3Asleep(Duration%3A%3Afrom_secs(2))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20thread%3A%3Aspawn(move%20%7C%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20loop%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20thread%3A%3Asleep(Duration%3A%3Afrom_secs(1))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22read%20shared%20%3D%20%3F%3F%3F%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C---%20%3F%3F%3F%3F%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20thread%3A%3Asleep(Duration%3A%3Afrom_secs(4))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22main%22)%3B%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0) (play.rust-lang.org)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code and your statements don't really make sense together. For example, there's nothing that prevents the second thread from finishing before the first thread ever has a chance to start. Yes, I see the sleeps, but **sleeping is not a viable concurrency solution**.

For the question as asked, I'd use a [*channel*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html). This allows one thread to produce a value and then transfer ownership of that value to another thread:

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc;

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

    let a = thread::spawn(move || {
        let large_value = 1;
        println!("write large_value {}", large_value);
        tx.send(large_value).expect("Unable to send");
    });

    let b = thread::spawn(move || {
        let large_value = rx.recv().expect("Unable to receive");
        println!("read shared = {}", large_value);
    });

    a.join().expect("Unable to join a");
    b.join().expect("Unable to join b");

    println!("main");
}
```

For the code as presented, there's really no other options besides a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or a [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html). This allows one thread to mutate the shared value for a while, then the other thread may read it for a while (subject to the vagaries of the OS scheduler):

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn main() {
    let shared = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));

    let shared_1 = shared.clone();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            let mut shared = shared_1.lock().expect("Unable to lock");
            *shared += 1;
            println!("write large_value {}", *shared);
        }
    });

    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            let shared = shared.lock().expect("Unable to lock");
            println!("read shared = {}", *shared);
        }
    });

    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    println!("main");
}
```

None of this is particularly unique to Rust; channels are quite popular in Go and Clojure and mutexes have existed for A Very Long Time. I'd suggest checking out any of the numerous beginner's guides on the Internet for multithreading and the perils therein.